# how to check program is writing to terminal

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, terminal

This is follow up to my question posted on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) - [Colorful output on terminal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120777/colorful-output-on-terminal) where I was trying to output coloured strings on terminal and detect it via `isatty()` call. However as @Jerry Coffin pointed out -

> You use isatty to check whether standard output is connected to a terminal, regardless of what stream you're writing to. This means the rest of the functions only work correctly if you pass `std::cout` as the stream to which they're going to write. Otherwise, you may allow formatting when writing to something that's not a TTY, and you may prohibit formatting when writing to something that is a TTY.

This was something that I wasn't aware of (read as *had no experience in*) and I wasn't even aware of the fact that cin/cout can be redirected elsewhere. So I tried to read more about it and found some existing questions on SO too. Here's what I've hacked together :

```
// initialize them at start of program - mandatory

std::streambuf const *coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();
std::streambuf const *cerrbuf = std::cerr.rdbuf();
std::streambuf const *clogbuf = std::clog.rdbuf();


// ignore this, just checks for TERM env var

inline bool supportsColor()
    {
        if(const char *env_p = std::getenv("TERM")) {
            const char *const term[8] = {
                "xterm", "xterm-256", "xterm-256color", "vt100",
                "color", "ansi",      "cygwin",         "linux"};
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
                if(std::strcmp(env_p, term[i]) == 0) return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

rightTerm = supportsColor();

// would make necessary checks to ensure in terminal

inline bool isTerminal(const std::streambuf *osbuf)
    {
        FILE *currentStream = nullptr;
        if(osbuf == coutbuf) {
            currentStream = stdout;
        }
        else if(osbuf == cerrbuf || osbuf == clogbuf) {
            currentStream = stderr;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        return isatty(fileno(currentStream));
    }

// this would print checking rightTerm && isTerminal calls

inline std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, rang::style v)
    {
        std::streambuf const *osbuf = os.rdbuf();

        return rightTerm && isTerminal(osbuf)
                   ? os << "\e[" << static_cast<int>(v) << "m"
                   : os;
    }
```

---

**My main issue is, although I've tested this manually, I'm not aware of the cases this might fail or bugs it might contain. Is this the right way to do this thing? Is there anything I might be missing?**

---

Here's a minimal example to get running (you'll also need a `in.txt` with random data):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

void f();
bool supportsColor();

// sample enum for foreground colors
enum class fg : unsigned char {
    def     = 39,
    black   = 30,
    red     = 31,
    green   = 32,
    yellow  = 33,
    blue    = 34,
    magenta = 35,
    cyan    = 36,
    gray    = 37
};

// initialize them at start of program - mandatory
// so that even if user redirects, we've a copy
std::streambuf const *coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();
std::streambuf const *cerrbuf = std::cerr.rdbuf();
std::streambuf const *clogbuf = std::clog.rdbuf();

// check if TERM supports color
bool rightTerm = supportsColor();

// Here is the implementation of isTerminal
// which checks if program is writing to Terminal or not
bool isTerminal(const std::streambuf *osbuf)
{
    FILE *currentStream = nullptr;
    if(osbuf == coutbuf) {
        currentStream = stdout;
    }
    else if(osbuf == cerrbuf || osbuf == clogbuf) {
        currentStream = stderr;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    return isatty(fileno(currentStream));
}

// will check if TERM supports color and isTerminal()
inline std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, fg v)
{
    std::streambuf const *osbuf = os.rdbuf();

    return rightTerm && isTerminal(osbuf)
               ? os << "\e[" << static_cast<int>(v) << "m"
               : os;
}


int main()
{

    std::cout << fg::red << "ERROR HERE! " << std::endl
              << fg::blue << "ERROR INVERSE?" << std::endl;

    std::ifstream in("in.txt");
    std::streambuf *Orig_cinbuf = std::cin.rdbuf(); // save old buf
    std::cin.rdbuf(in.rdbuf()); // redirect std::cin to in.txt!

    std::ofstream out("out.txt");
    std::streambuf *Orig_coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(); // save old buf
    std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf()); // redirect std::cout to out.txt!

    std::string word;
    std::cin >> word;                      // input from the file in.txt
    std::cout << fg::blue << word << "  "; // output to the file out.txt

    f(); // call function

    std::cin.rdbuf(Orig_cinbuf);   // reset to standard input again
    std::cout.rdbuf(Orig_coutbuf); // reset to standard output again

    std::cin >> word;  // input from the standard input
    std::cout << word; // output to the standard input
    return 0;
}

void f()
{
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, line)) // input from the file in.txt
    {
        std::cout << fg::green << line << "\n"; // output to the file out.txt
    }
}

bool supportsColor()
{
    if(const char *env_p = std::getenv("TERM")) {
        const char *const term[8] = {"xterm",  "xterm-256", "xterm-256color",
                                     "vt100",  "color",     "ansi",
                                     "cygwin", "linux"};
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
            if(std::strcmp(env_p, term[i]) == 0) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

<sup>I've also tagged `c` language although this is `c++` code because the relevant code is shared b/w two and I don't want to miss any suggestions</sup>

Comment: Minimize the code please, only relevant portion should do

Comment: You can test with things like `test | less` or `test > test.txt`.

Comment: @tadman ^ answers _"the question"_.

Comment: As a note, you might want to ease up on using `inline` so aggressively. I highly doubt your TTY detection code is performance critical. You probably want to declare that only when it's strictly necessary.

Comment: Why not to look at some existing and stable project? For example, [here](https://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=blob;f=Source/kwsys/Terminal.c;h=a8abb6cc680272638d27a33de29ddd0a33d024b3;hb=HEAD) is how terminal detection is implemented in CMake (along with a list of vt100 compatible terminals).

Comment: @AngelusMortis I've made the edits.

Comment: @tadman I've tested with those as well as actual writing to the file from within the code. So far it works. But as I didn't knew about the fact that `cout` can be redirected, I am not sure about it that I'm not making any mistakes. That's why I posted it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this only includes cases on terminals, and then there is redirection of cout buffer to a file buffer case too. Anyways I've checked them both manually :)

Comment: @tadman I wasn't using inline so much until I saw `function included in multiple source files must be inline` inside this page - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

Comment: @gudok Thankyou. This resource will help me tremendously :)

Comment: @tadman, `inline` is only indirectly related to performance, it means the function body can appear in a multiple translation units (i.e. in a header) without getting multiple definition errors.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal That's because you shouldn't be defining methods in your header files. This is a bad practice that `inline` only serves to sweep under the carpet.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Just because you *can* define code in header files with `inline` doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP's question:

> My main issue is, although I've tested this manually, I'm not aware of the cases this might fail or bugs it might contain. Is this the right way to do this thing? Is there anything I might be missing?

Not all terminals support all features; in addition, the `TERM` variable is used most often to select a particular *terminal description*.

The usual approach to this is to use the terminal database rather than hard-coding things.  Doing that, your methods

```
inline bool supportsColor()

inline std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, rang::style v)
```

would check the terminal capabilities, e.g., using `tigetnum` (for the number of colors), `tigetstr` (for the actual escape sequences which the terminal is supposed to support).  You could just as easily wrap those as the `isatty` function.

Further reading:

- [interface to terminal database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html)
- [terminal database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html#download_database)
- [My terminal doesn't recognize color](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#no_color) (ncurses FAQ)

Answer (score 4):

To check on POSIX that the standard output is a terminal, just use [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html)

```
 if (isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)) {
   /// handle the stdout is terminal case
 }
```

You might also use `/dev/tty`, see [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html); e.g. if your program `myprog` is started in a command pipeline like `./myprog some arguments | less` you could still `fopen("/dev/tty","w")` to output to the controlling terminal (even if *stdout* is then a pipe).

Sometimes, a program is run without any controlling terminal, e.g. thru [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) or [at(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at)

Comment: I'm already using `isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)` since `isatty(fileno(stdout))` is same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why no one suggest the solution for 8 years :/

We can use inheritance of std::ostream and try upgrading to std::ofstream with dynamic cast:

```
void write(std::ostream& os = std::cout)
{   
    std::ofstream* fileStream = dynamic_cast<std::ofstream*>(&os);
    if (fileStream)
        std::cout << "It's a file\n";
    else 
        std::cout << "It's not a file\n";

    os << "Hello, StackOverflow\n";
};


std::ofstream file("./build/test.txt");
write();
write(file);
```

Comment: This can fail when you are writing to standard output that is redirected elsewhere, as mentioned in the question.